# How to parse values from a sql column in a loop using a stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, parsing, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012

I have a multiple tables of the same structure, each representing a different customer. In each of these tables there are multiple columns with various strings of data where the values are separated by a blank space like so:

```
Domain_Name | Account_ID | SiteID | Account_Name | BotExceptions | BlockCountries | BlockedURLs |BlockedIPs
www.Domain1.com | 123456 |987654  | account1 | TR Sites24x7 Tools/ | UK FR IR| www.url1.com/someRsc www.url2.com/someRsc|46.218.22.145 64.129.104.70 92.44.168.111
www.Domain2.com | 345678|321098| account2 | TR Sites24x7 Tools/ | ES GR AX BE| www.url1.com/someRsc www.url2.com/someRsc|46.218.22.145 64.129.104.70 92.44.168.111
```

So in each column all the items (IPs/Bot names/Countries/URLs) are concatenated to a single string delimited by a single blank space. For example "TR Sites24x7 Tools/" is actually "TR","Sites24x7" and "Tools/". I'm looking for a way to build a stored procedure and using sql / Tsql, parse the string in each column and place the items into rows similar to that:

```
Domain_Name | Account_ID | SiteID | Account_Name | BotExceptions | BlockCountries | BlockedURLs |BlockedIPs
www.Domain1.com| 123456  | 987654 | account1     | TR            | UK             | www.url1.com/someRsc       | 46.218.22.145
www.Domain1.com| 123456  | 987654 | account1     | Sites24x7     | FR             | www.url2.com/someRsc       | 64.129.104.70
```

In other words place each value in a row of its own while keeping the first 4 columns static throughout the table. Since the data is already in tables in sql server 2012 DB I figured it would be simpler to have an SP or a function that would do this parsing but I'm not very proficient with that language and could use some help. Thank you.

Comment: This is a terrible design. First, **Never ever** keep multiple values in a single column, and second, There is almost never a justification to keep multiple tables with the same structure and same meaning.
Your target design is also not good. The correct design would be to add a table for each column where you currently have multiple values, that will contain a forgiegn key to the primary table and a single value. Also, unify the different customers tables into a single table.

Comment: I agree with @ZoharPeled, but I'm hoping that part of the reason that you're asking this is because you're trying to normalize the data a bit.  It really is quite awful...

Comment: I agree the original table's design is less then optimal. It's the result of an outside script which I don't have control of so this raw data is by default in the structure I've shown above. It may be worth changing my target design to multiple tables, each one for one of the columns in the original tables, after parsing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create and populate sample table (**Please** save us this step in your future questions)

```
DECLARE @T AS TABLE 
(
    Domain_Name varchar(200), -- or whatever length suits your needs
    Account_ID int, 
    SiteID int, 
    Account_Name varchar(200),    
    BotExceptions varchar(200), 
    BlockCountries varchar(200)
)

INSERT INTO @T VALUES 
('www.Domain1.com', 123456, 987654, 'account1', 'TR Sites24x7 Tools/', 'UK FR IR'),
('www.Domain2.com', 21478, 987654, 'account1', 'TR Sites24x7 Tools/', 'USA IT FR')
```

Here is how I would create the **target tables**

```
CREATE TABLE DomainAccounts
(
    Id int identity(1,1),
    Domain_Name varchar(200), -- or whatever length suits your needs
    Account_ID int, 
    SiteID int, 
    Account_Name varchar(200),-- or whatever length suits your needs
    CONSTRAINT PK_DomainAccounts PRIMARY KEY (Id)
)

CREATE TABLE BotExceptions
(
    DomainAccounts_Id int,
    BotName varchar(200),  -- or whatever length suits your needs
    CONSTRAINT FK_BotExceptions_DomainAccounts FOREIGN KEY (DomainAccounts_Id) REFERENCES DomainAccounts(Id)
)

CREATE TABLE BlockCountries
(
    DomainAccounts_Id int,
    CountryName varchar(200),  -- or whatever length suits your needs
    CONSTRAINT FK_BlockCountries_DomainAccounts FOREIGN KEY (DomainAccounts_Id) REFERENCES DomainAccounts(Id)
)
```

Also, **create 2 more tables** the same way - `BlockedURLs` and `BlockedIPs`

Then, Create a **string splitting function.** I've used A function based on Jeff Moden's splitter taken from Aaron Bertrand's S[plit strings the right way – or the next best way](https://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings). Feel free to use a different one.

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.SplitStrings
(
   @List NVARCHAR(MAX),
   @Delimiter NVARCHAR(255)
)
RETURNS TABLE
WITH SCHEMABINDING AS
RETURN
  WITH E1(N)        AS ( SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 
                         UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 
                         UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1),
       E2(N)        AS (SELECT 1 FROM E1 a, E1 b),
       E4(N)        AS (SELECT 1 FROM E2 a, E2 b),
       E42(N)       AS (SELECT 1 FROM E4 a, E2 b),
       cteTally(N)  AS (SELECT 0 UNION ALL SELECT TOP (DATALENGTH(ISNULL(@List,1))) 
                         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) FROM E42),
       cteStart(N1) AS (SELECT t.N+1 FROM cteTally t
                         WHERE (SUBSTRING(@List,t.N,1) = @Delimiter OR t.N = 0))
  SELECT Item = SUBSTRING(@List, s.N1, ISNULL(NULLIF(CHARINDEX(@Delimiter,@List,s.N1),0)-s.N1,8000))
    FROM cteStart s;
```

**Finally**, Insert the records from the source table into the target tables:

```
INSERT INTO DomainAccounts (Domain_Name, Account_ID, SiteID, Account_Name)
SELECT Domain_Name, Account_ID, SiteID, Account_Name
FROM @T

INSERT INTO BotExceptions (DomainAccounts_Id, BotName)
SELECT da.Id, Item
FROM @T t 
INNER JOIN DomainAccounts da ON t.Domain_Name = da.Domain_Name
                            AND t.Account_ID = da.Account_ID
                            AND t.SiteID = da.SiteID
                            AND t.Account_Name = da.Account_Name

CROSS APPLY dbo.SplitStrings(BotExceptions, ' ') 
WHERE LEN(LTRIM(RTRIM(Item))) > 0

INSERT INTO BlockCountries (DomainAccounts_Id,CountryName)
SELECT da.Id, Item
FROM @T t 
INNER JOIN DomainAccounts da ON t.Domain_Name = da.Domain_Name
                            AND t.Account_ID = da.Account_ID
                            AND t.SiteID = da.SiteID
                            AND t.Account_Name = da.Account_Name

CROSS APPLY dbo.SplitStrings(BlockCountries, ' ') 
WHERE LEN(LTRIM(RTRIM(Item))) > 0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a function like this one:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[UDF_StringDelimiter]
/*********************************************************
**  Takes Parameter "LIST" and transforms it for use    **
**  to select individual values or ranges of values.    **
**                                                      **
**  EX: 'This,is,a,test' = 'This' 'Is' 'A' 'Test'       **
*********************************************************/
    (
          @LIST             VARCHAR(8000)
         ,@DELIMITER        VARCHAR(255)
    )

RETURNS @TABLE TABLE 
    ( 
         [RowID] INT IDENTITY
        ,[Value] VARCHAR(255)
    )
WITH SCHEMABINDING  
AS 
BEGIN
    DECLARE 
         @LISTLENGTH AS SMALLINT
        ,@LISTCURSOR AS SMALLINT
        ,@VALUE AS VARCHAR(255)
    ;
    SELECT 
         @LISTLENGTH = LEN(@LIST) - LEN(REPLACE(@LIST,@DELIMITER,'')) + 1
        ,@LISTCURSOR = 1
        ,@VALUE = ''
    ;
    WHILE @LISTCURSOR <= @LISTLENGTH
    BEGIN

        INSERT INTO @TABLE (Value)
        SELECT 
            CASE
                WHEN @LISTCURSOR < @LISTLENGTH
                    THEN SUBSTRING(@LIST,1,PATINDEX('%' + @DELIMITER + '%',@LIST) - 1)
                ELSE SUBSTRING(@LIST,1,LEN(@LIST))
            END
        ;
        SET @LIST = STUFF(@LIST,1,PATINDEX('%' + @DELIMITER + '%',@LIST),'')
        ;       
        SET @LISTCURSOR = @LISTCURSOR + 1
        ;
    END
    ;
    RETURN
    ;
END
;
```

In this instance, you would use it like this:

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.UDF_StringDelimiter(BotExceptions,' ')
;
```

This would return a list of values like this:

```
RowID         Value
--------------------
1             TR
2             Sites24x7 
3             Tools
```

Using various methods (a `JOIN` or `CROSS APPLY`), you can then use this to insert new rows to the table.

I would imagine you would want to join to these function results `WHERE RowID >= 2`, which would add only a second, third, fourth, nth row.  The first row, where the original string was held, can be updated to remove all subsequent values in a second batch, using the same function, `WHERE RowID = 1`.

Would that help?